# What SQL query for multiple rows with one value the same in each?

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert an XML file of the following kind:

```
<thing>
    <name>one</name>
    <type>metal</type>
    <type>round</type>
</thing>
<thing>
    <name>two</name>
    <type>round</type>
</thing>
<thing>
    <name>three</name>
    <type>metal</type>
    <type>round</type>
</thing>
```

into an SQL database. There are lots of `<thing>` elements and each has one or more `<type>` elements. There are a lot of things, but only a few repeated different patterns of the `<type>` element which each thing might have, so I have created a table of `thing`, which has columns `id` and `pattern`, a table of `pattern`, a table of `type_pattern` which has columns `type_id` and `pattern_id`, and a table of `type` which has a `txt` column for the word, such as `metal` or `round`, and an `id` column. As I parse the XML file, I wish to categorize each `thing` into a particular `type_pattern`, which is the pattern of types which it matches. For example, things `one` and `three` in the above match a pattern of having `metal` and `round` type, but thing `two` has a different pattern of only `round` type. So the database table for the above might look like

**thing**

```
 id   pattern_id name
 1    1          one
 2    2          two
 3    1          three
```

**type_pattern**

```
 pattern_id type_id
 1          1
 1          2
 2          1
```

**type**

```
 id  txt
 1   metal
 2   round
```

The point is, I want to not have a table of thing and type, but a table of `thing`, `type_pattern`, and `type`.

**My question is, given a list of types, how should I write an SQL query to get the pattern id?**

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

i would consider

thing as an entity
and
type as an entity (don't know if it really is an entity or an value object)

so accordingly you would have a thing table and a type table

```
thing-table:
id | name

type table:
id | txt
```

and then a many-to-many table say

```
thingTypes:
thingId | typeId
```

when you wish to select all the types of a thing just query the thingTypes for thingId = "the specific thing id". and alternatively you can query the thingTypes for a specific typeId and get all thingIds back that reference the specific type.

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of `thing` elements, but they all have one of only a few different patterns of possible selections of `type` elements, which is why I have a separate table for `pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of types in the list before executing:

```
select pattern_id
from type_pattern
where type_id in (...list of types...)
group by pattern_id
having count(*) = #of types in the list
```

Alternatively, you could sort the result by the number of matched types, so you'll get which pattern matches completely, and which patterns are a close match:

```
select pattern_id, count(*) matches
from type_pattern
where type_id in (...list of types...)
group by pattern_id
order by 2 desc
```

**Update:** If you do not want the patterns that fit even more types, you can constrain the query like this:

```
select pattern_id
from type_pattern t1
where type_id in (...list of types...) and not exists ( 
    select 1 
    from type_pattern t2 
    where t2.pattern_id = t1.pattern_id
    and t2.type_id not in (...list of types...))
group by pattern_id
having count(*) = #of types in the list
```

or, if you still want to rank the patterns, here's the query that shows how much "hits" and "misses" each pattern has, and ranks them by "hits":

```
select pattern_id, 
    sum(case when type_id in (...list of types...) then 1 else 0 end) matches, 
    sum(case when type_id in (...list of types...) then 0 else 1 end) extras 
from type_pattern
group by pattern_id
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: This doesn't completely solve the problem, since it detects multiple patterns which match even if the pattern has more types which don't match.